# Get last one-digit number after word

Tags: grep

How to get the last one-digit number (**bold**) with regex, without including other numerical values:

Fund**1**
abcd**2**
Rail**1**
50 000 13.2
2Fund
Train**2**

Have tried various regex, but can't manage to get only the single numeric value at the end of each word.

Comment: If your engine supports lookbehind, you could try `(?<=[a-z])\d(?=\s|$)`

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @Spada Which editor/regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU grep`:

```bash
$ echo 'Fund1 abcd2 Rail1 50 000 13.2 2Fund Train2' | grep -oP '[a-z]\K\d\b'
1
2
1
2
```

`-P` option enables PCRE. `[a-z]\K` matches lowercase alphabets, but won't be part of the matched portion. `\d` matches a digit character and `\b` ensures it is matched at the end of a word.

Add `-i` option if you want to match alphabets case-insensitively.